# How can i serialize Django View object?

Tags: python, django, ajax, serialization, view

I want to serialize my context data, but i get this error: TypeError: < tests.views.ExamView object at 0x7f8e18873668 > is not JSON serializable

Here is my code:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

        context = self.get_context_data()
        html = render_to_string('difficult_test.html', context)

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return http.JsonResponse({"html":html, 'context':context})

        return response
```

Comment: your context must be a dict that contains primitive type, int, str, ...

Comment: or a serializable object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Primitive types get serialized you have `tests.views.ExamView` it is Class view object in context please remove few items from context which have class object. You can log it to know how many class objects are coming in context. If you need class object data also then you need to serialize it manually

```
delete self.context['view']
```

Django's Generic API view have get_serializer_context() like

```
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
           'request': self.request,
           'format': self.format_kwarg,
           'view': self
        }
```